# MySQL NO CASE SENSITIVE Search Data for Keywords Using LIKE but Data is in Hexadecimal format (Not Text Format)

Tags: mysql, sql, hex, sql-like

I have a Database where all data in relevant column is in Hexadecimal Format say for word ABSENT we have data IN hexadecimal format 414453454e54

I want to conduct SEARCH for records with Specific Text that too in Hexadecimal format (SELECT.....LIKE '%414453454e54%'

How can i search for records for such keywords "414453454e54" in a Non Case Sensitive manner.Meaning a Search for 414453454e54 (i.e ABSENT) should return all records containing ABSENT in any Case (ABSENT,absent) or Mixed Case (Absent,abseNt) in hexadecimal format.

I HAVE TRIED TO USE THE UPPER (), LOWER () AND MANY SUCH OPTIONS AVAILABLE ON NET BUT NONE SEEM TO BE WORKING AS IT IS IN HEXADECIMAL FORMAT.

Awaiting a Quick Resolution

Comment: Simple answer is that you cant - because upper & lower case characters have different numeric values - so the hexadecimal values are completely different - Uppercase A is x41 lower case is x61. You would need to convert from the hexadecimal value to the string & do a case-insensitive comparison on that.

Comment: any other way out and if nit then how to convert to string ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [unhex()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) method of MySQL, and cast it as char in the where clause.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    col
FROM
    table
WHERE
    CAST(UNHEX(col) AS CHAR) LIKE '%ABSENT%'
```

Be aware though, that this isn't very performance friendly. It may run slower and slower the more records your table holds.

Comment: Yeah, this will be very slow, but it's probably the cleanest way. If you're using MySQL 5.7+ one improvement might be to use a stored [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns) which is, say, `UPPER(UNHEX(col))` and then put an index on it. Of course, the real answer is not to store character data you want to search as a stream of hexadecimal in the first place...